# Scala 2.8 Actors

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, actor, akka

We're looking at using actors in our Scala code quite soon. We're also thinking of moving to Scala 2.8 in the next few weeks. We've been keeping an eye on Akka but it doesn't currently support 2.8 and plans for it have [slipped](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/54-scala-2-8-support-) from the 0.7 release to 0.8

We would like distributed, supervised actors. Is there an alternative to Akka? Or does anyone know if Akka 0.8 will definitely have 2.8 support (and when it's scheduled for)? Perhaps it's possible to just use Scala actors for the time being and switch to Akka at a later stage?

Thanks,

Dave

Update:
The branch Viktor mentions below can be followed [here](http://github.com/jboner/akka/commits/2.8-WIP)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm on the Akka team and yes, we definitely want 2.8 support ready for 0.8.

Akka has an experimental 2.8 branch if you like living on the bleeding edge, it's a bit behind the current master due to the recent work to get 0.7 ready for prime time, but it's getting there.

Comment: That's great news Viktor. Do you know the timeline for 0.8? Or will 0.7 have a branch that supports Scala 2.8? This is for a production system so nothing too bleeding edge ;)

Comment: 0.7 currently has a (although a bit dated, but I'm working on catching up to current master) 2.8 branch named 2.8-WIP

Comment: The 2.8-WIP branch has since a couple of days been forwarded to reach master.

Answer (score 2):

Akka will move to 2.8 today, latest tomorrow, as part of the 0.8 release.

/Jonas

Comment: We're moving to 2.8 in the next few days too so that's great news. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not personally involved with the Akka effort, I feel reasonably confident that Akka will be ported to Scala 2.8 as soon as Scala 2.8.0 is actually available.

Comment: Unfortunately we'll be on 2.8-beta-1 soon. There are too many bug fixes and improvements we need for us to wait until 2.8 final in a few months.